# c++ constrain template parameter in pointer for a template function

Tags: c++11, templates

I am working on a code base using core c++11 language features without the support of the standard library. So everything in the namespace std is implemented by a vendor who is no longer touch c++ for several years.

The thing I am trying to do is a cleanup function which is recycling allocated memory from `std::vector<T*>`.

```
template<typename T>
void Cleanup(std::vector<T*> &v)
{
    for(T*& p : v)
    {
        delete p;
        p = nullptr;
    }
}
```

It kind of working. But I think it would be good to put some limitations on the input parameter, so only a pointer can be passed in the function kind like `std::is_pointer<T>` in the std. Any idea of how to do that without std?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#define EOL "\n"
class A{
    public:
    A():data(0){}
    int data; 
};
class B{};

std::vector<A*> va;
std::vector<B*> vb;


int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        va.push_back(new A());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        vb.push_back(new B());
    }


    std::cout << va.size() << " : "<<  vb.size() << std::endl;
    Cleanup(va);
    Cleanup(vb);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<va.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(va[i] != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to clean : " << va[i] << "["<< va[i]->data <<"]" << EOL; 
        }
    }
}
```

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot implement `is_pointer` in your own application's namespace?

Comment: That is my question, how to

Comment: Consider getting a working standard library implementation.

Comment: Take a look at a possible implementation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer.

Comment: The implementation is small enough to fit in a comment! `template<typename T>struct is_pointer{static constexpr bool value=false;};template<typename E>struct is_pointer<E*>{static constexpr bool value=true;};`. Of course, it's a little longer if you want to handle `int *const` and `int *volatile`.

Comment: I'm confused about your question, your current code only works with vectors of raw pointers. What more constraining do you want to get out of this?

Comment: Side note: What compiler/platform are you using? If g++ or clang++, you can most likely use their standard library as well.